# Python conversion of dictionary value from list to string while writing to json

Tags: python, json, string, list, format

my source dictionary is something like this (just mentioning few columns for example)

```
{'aws_resource_name': 'abcd', 'resource_type': 'instance', 'policies': ['LAB_TEMP']}
```

What I am trying  to get list like values as string in json format

```
info=[]
    Account_Name=acc_name
    for resource in result[acc_name]["resources"]:
        if (Hostname==resource["aws_resource_name"]):
            print(resource)
            #Policy =(resource["policies"]) 
            Policy = resource['policies']
            info.append({"Account Name": Account_Name ,"policy Name": Policy })
    print(info)
```

**Current output:**

```
[{'Account Name': 'xxxxxx', 'policy Name': ['LAB_TEMP']}]
```

**expected output:**

```
[{'Account Name': 'xxxxxx', 'policy Name': 'LAB_TEMP'}]
```

Problem is some of the values are in source dict is list type, i need to convert into string while i print to json finally

Comment: you can do resource['policies'][0] right?

Comment: yes, u are right... helped. it worked .just a question silly might be for example is this example also correct ? `( ', '.join(resource['policies'])`

Comment: So your resource['policies'] may contain more than one element?

Comment: as of now yes only 1, that means` [0]` only works if its has single value in list ? incase if i have multiple values like this ['sam','chaitu','john'], if i need to select 3rd value for output then resource['policies'][3]

Comment: It is 0 indexing so resource['policies'][2] will give you the third element (john)

Comment: my bad, yeah index starts with zero ...:) thank you..it helps

Comment: so `resource['policies'][2][3]` also allowed right to get multiple values ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217203/discussion-between-sai-sreenivas-and-asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your use case involves that the "POLICY" list will either have just one value or the first value is what would be needed then you just need to add the 0th index to your code i.e. Policy = resource['policies'][0]
In case it can have no values as well at times, then you would need to add a check for that as well

Comment: that means` [0]` only works if its has single value in list ? incase if i have multiple values like this `['sam','chaitu','john']`, if i need to select 3rd value for output then `resource['policies'][3] `?